Kerberos authentication with GSSAPI on Windows 11 LTSC fails with [An unsupported mechanism was requested (Unknown error)]
We have a Windows 11 LTSC client that fails authentication with - Apache2 / Kerberos / GSSAPI.
This configuration works with all of our clients, Windows 10, Windows 10 LTSC, Windows 11, but not Windows 11 LTSC.
Error in apache2 log:
[Wed Oct 30 13:36:14.996279 2024] [auth_gssapi:error] [pid 585:tid 585] [client 192.168.202.150:50755] GSS 
ERROR In Negotiate Auth: gss_accept_sec_context() failed: [An unsupported mechanism was requested (Unknown error)]
Keytab file :
ktpass -princ HTTP/xxx.xxx.fr@XXX.FR -mapuser ssowpintranet@XXX.FR -pass StrongPassword123** -crypto All -kvno 8 -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -out c:\wpintranet.keytab

krb5.conf :
[libdefaults]
   default_realm = XXX.FR
   kdc_timesync = 1
   ccache_type = 4
   forwardable = false
   proxiable = false
   fcc-mit-ticketflags = false

   default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac
   default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac
   permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac
   preferred_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac


[realms]
   XXX.FR = {
     kdc = dc1.xxx.fr:88
     admin_server = dc1.xxx.fr:88
     default_domain = XXX.FR
   }
[domain_realm]
   .xxx.fr = XXX.FR
   xxx.fr = XXX.FR

apache2 conf :
.....
<IfModule !mod_auth_gssapi.c>
   LoadModule auth_gssapi_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_auth_gssapi.so
</IfModule>
<Directory /var/www/wordpress>
   AuthType GSSAPI
   AuthName "Kerberos auth"
   GssapiCredStore keytab:/etc/apache2/wpintranet.keytab
   Require valid-user
</Directory>
.....

If anyone can help me.
Thank you

Can you verify that the client OS is able to obtain both a TGT for the realm and a service ticket for the HTTP/foo, e.g. from klist or Wireshark? Are you using Firefox or non-Firefox as the client? Does the web server's AD account have the "Supports AES 256" option set on it? (And vice versa, perhaps it unnecessarily has "Supports AES 128" set?)

Windows 11 LTSC is effectively a new release of Windows 11 this month. I don't see anything documented, but it may be using something that isn't supported in the host application (SHA-3-TLS 1.3). How that translates to Kerberos encryption types I'm not sure.  Note that on a feature parity comparison, Windows 11 is five full years of features later from Windows 10 LTSC. LTSC also isn't similar in practice to normal Windows, due to it is exclusively for embedded devices that don't tolerate change well, and can't be used with anything modern/useful like Office/Office 365.

Thank you so much, my problem is solved !
"Does the web server's AD account have the "Supports AES 256" option set on it?"
Forget to check this box in account settings ...
Thank you
